# Form Authentication using multiple Login Forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, web-config

How can I use form authentication when I have three login forms and I dont want to use Role Table. Can anyone help me? I have three login forms for three different roles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using Role Table and if there are only Three Roles, You can simply create a Session Variable for Role for Each form then User login is Successful before redirecting to next page.

Then check The role session variable value in other pages.

Hope this helps..!!!